# Python programming: Global name 'is_within' is not defined. I'm using filter for lists

Tags: python, list, filter, global, defined

```
class wordlist:
    def is_within(word):
        return 3 <= (len(word)) <= 5
    def truncate_by_length(wordlist):
        return filter(is_within, wordlist)
    newWordlist = truncate_by_length(['mark', 'daniel', 'mateo', 'jison'])
    print newWordList
```

Basically what it does is, given a min and max values for a length of a word, (in the given example is 3 and 5 respectively), it should print a new list of words that are within those lengths from a given original length. For example above, given the words mark, daniel, mateo and jison, it should print the new list only containing mark, mateo and jison.

Whenever I run it, I received the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Makoy/Documents/AMC 125/sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    class wordlist:
  File "C:/Users/Makoy/Documents/AMC 125/sample.py", line 6, in wordlist
    newWordlist = truncate_by_length(['mark', 'daniel', 'mateo', 'jison'])
  File "C:/Users/Makoy/Documents/AMC 125/sample.py", line 5, in truncate_by_length
    return filter(is_within, wordlist)
NameError: global name 'is_within' is not defined
```

I'm sorry if I sounds so noob and such but I've just started studying Python a month ago and I'm a complete beginner with it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call 'self' (so, self.is_within in your example) if you're calling a class method within a class method definition. Your first parameter for the class methods should also be 'self' which refers to this instance of the class. Check out [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) for a good explanation.

```
class wordlist:
    def is_within(self, word):
        return 3 <= (len(word)) <= 5
    def truncate_by_length(self,wordlist):
        return filter(self.is_within, wordlist)

wl = wordlist()    
newWordList = wl.truncate_by_length(['mark', 'daniel', 'mateo', 'jison'])
print newWordList
```

Comment: `self` is an ordinary variable like any other; it's just convention that it's the name of the first argument to methods. His methods do not have a `self` parameter, so he'll get a `NameError` on `self`.

Comment: Good day! I just did what you've said but still receiving the same error. Have I missed something? Just like what icktoofay said.

Comment: @ictoofay thankyou for that clarification, you are completely correct and I have modified my answer as such

Comment: @MacMac please check my updated answer. There are a few problems with your code. Firstly, you need to add 'self' as the first parameter to your class method functions. Next you need to create an instance of 'wordlist' before you can perform the truncate_by_length method. There is a better way to structure this code but hopefully this will help you understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by timc explains why your code gives an error and how to fix it, the current design of your class is rather poor. Your the wordlist class only holds two methods that operate on external data - in general there's no need to create a class for this, you could just define them directly in the global scope of your module. A better design for a wordlist class would be something like this:

```
class wordlist():
    def __init__(self, wlist):
        #save the word list as an instance variable
        self._wlist = wlist

    def truncate_by_length(self):
        #truncante the word list using a list comprehension
        self._wlist = [word for word in self._wlist if 3 <= len(word) <= 5]

    def __str__(self):
        #string representation of the class is the word list as a string
        return str(self._wlist)
```

Use it like this:

```
w = wordlist(['mark', 'daniel', 'mateo', 'jison'])
w.truncate_by_length()
print w
```